# KeyError: 'Date'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nsepy import get_history
import datetime as dt
start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)

end = dt.datetime.today()

infy = get_history(symbol='INFY', start = start, end = end)
infy.index = pd.to_datetime(infy.index)
infy.head()
infy_volume = infy.groupby(infy['Date'].dt.year).reset_index().Volume.sum().
```

> "Error showed as Date", but Infy_volume should be a multi-index series
>   with two levels of index - Year and Month

.

Comment: You have `Date` column as index so use `infy.groupby(infy.index.year).Volume.sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Abhi bro thank you. Where can I learn python in depth like you.

Comment: @Abhi please post an answer so we can mark this question resolved.

Comment: @Alex Done.. :)

Comment: @skjainmiah Just keep on practicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the `date` column as index so use

```
infy.groupby(infy.index.year).Volume.sum().reset_index()
```

If you want to `groupby` with year and month use

```
infy_volume = infy.groupby([infy.index.year, infy.index.month]).Volume.sum()
infy_volume.index = infy_volume.index.rename('Month', level=1)
print(infy_volume)
# infy_volume.reset_index()
```

Comment: infy.groupby([infy.index.year, infy.index.month]).volume.sum() is getting an error "Duplicated level name: "Date", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0 ".

Comment: same error bro " Duplicated level name: "Date", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0."